# Is there any plugin or page builder for question and multiple answers (for manual entry)

Tags: wordpress

actually, I am building a WordPress MCQS website, where I have excel sheet of 17k question and each question has multiple answers, it's not like Quiz ...
but I want to show them like Question and multiple answers ....
I have tried inserting them manually in HTML code but I am unable to get pagination...

So, is there any plugin, builder or anything that can show the MCQS with answers ..

I want something like this.

Q : what is 1+1 ?

A.2

B.3

c.4

And per page 20 Questions and then fine pagination for rest of the MCQs

I have inserted the Questions and multiple answers in HTML ...
But pagination is not fine over there ...

Comment: have seen something like this in wordpress plugin repository.

Comment: thanks for your help Dear ! but i am unable to find such plugin in wordpress plugins or on google ...For precisely i want to show my MCQS like this website 
https://pakmcqs.com/

Comment: So you want correct answer to be highlighted in the option rather than giving user option to select ?

Comment: exactly this is what i am looking for ? cuz if i'll go with custom ,then pagination is blowing my mind.

Comment: I don't think there is any plugin. You can do it with custom coding

Comment: hi thanks for you precious time ! m on it <3

Answer (score -1):

I would go with WATU Pro, it is an online test plugin/platform for WordPress that allows for the creation of sophisticated Multiple choice quizzes and tests. Chiefly, it allows for the import of CSVs which you could convert your spreadsheet to and upload it. It even provides an example CSV on the site for you. https://calendarscripts.info/watupro/

Comment: thanks for your answer, Dear ... Actually WATU is about quizzes thing and the answer should be selected by user but actually, i want something like this 
https://pakmcqs.com/

Comment: hm, I see, so it will literally just be a list of questions and answers with the correct answer highlighted? Maybe try creating a custom post tupe using CPT UI (https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) then adding custom fields to it using ACF (https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) the fields would be question, answer 1, answer 2, answer3, answer 4. You could then think of each question and answer set as a single post and import them that way. WP All Import should work here